# Unable to connect AWS RDS to Application

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, sequelize.js, amazon-rds

I made AWS RDS instance made, Publicly accessible "Yes", have default VPC security group, have two imbound rules one default one and one custom rule as below

```
Name : 
Security group rule ID : sgr-0d64f2e55ff6cf13d
IP version : IPv4
Type : PostgreSQL
Protocol : TCP
Port range : 5432
Source : 0.0.0.0/0
Description :
```

i'm able to connect using psql but when i try to connect using node & sequelize i get this error

```
Unable to connect to the database: ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xx.xx", user "abhinay", database "tenant-core", no encryption
```

same in log: error/postgresql.log.2023-10-27-06

```
2023-10-27 06:14:42 UTC:xxx.xxx.xx.xx(58328):abhinay@tenant-core:[8289]:FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "xxx.xxx.xx.xx", user "abhinay", database "tenant-core", no encryption
```

node db config

```
const { Sequelize } = require("sequelize");
const { PGHOST, PGUSER, PGDATABASE, PGPASSWORD } = require("../../env");

const sequelize = new Sequelize(PGDATABASE, PGUSER, PGPASSWORD, {
    host: PGHOST,
    dialect: "postgres",
    operatorsAliases: 0,
    logging: false,
    pool: {
        max: 5,
        min: 0,
        acquire: 30000,
        idle: 10000,
    }
})

const connectionTest = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
    }
}
connectionTest()
```

Comment: Can you add `telnet RDS_HOST 5432` to show that you are able to to connect to the RDS Host publicly?

Comment: And does your `tenant-core` database exist?

Comment: i tried telnet getting error ```telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out```

Comment: Is your RDS in a public subnet?

Comment: yes its publicly accessible

Comment: RDS is configured to refuse connections without encryption, and node has not been configured to use ssl and so refuses to do so.  Change one, or change the other.  psql works because by default it is willing use Diffie-Helman-like encryption even if it can't verify the cert.